# The image of linear operator, $T(\ell ^{\infty})$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$T:(\ell^\infty, \|\cdot\|_\infty) \rightarrow (\ell^\infty, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ with $T(b_1,b_2,\ldots)=(b_1, b_2/2, b_3/3,\ldots)$ is a bounded linear operator.

Show that $w = (1, 1/\sqrt2, 1 /\sqrt3,\ldots, 1 /\sqrt n, 1 /\sqrt{n+1}, \ldots)$ does not belong to $T(ℓ^∞)$, the image of the operator $T$ but is one of the accumulation points of the image of $T$.

---

$w$ seems like it is not in the image because of those square roots. I am not sure what it means by accumulation but I guess that if $(b_n)=(1,1,1,1,\ldots)$ then $b_1$ would be the same as $w_1$.

But really unsure on all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $w$ is in the image of $T$ then $w=(b_1/1,b_2/2,\dots$) for some bounded sequence $(b_n)$, but then $$\frac{b_n}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$ hence $b_n=\sqrt n$ which is not bounded.

---

An accumulation point is the same as a limit point it just means that for any neighbourhood $U$ of $w$ there is a point $x\in \mathrm{Im}(T)$ such that $x\in U$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second part please. Do you mean that the limit of $w$ is the same as the limit of $(b_1, b_2/2,...)$?

Comment: @snowman Given a topological space $X$ and a subspace $S$, we say that $x\in X$ is an accumulation point of $S$ if every neighbourhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $S$ different from $x$ itself.